# Angular Typescript Error - charset is deprecated. (deprecation)

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7. I have loadscript.directive.ts

```html
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLoadscript]'
})

export class LoadscriptDirective {

  @Input('appLoadscript') script: any;

  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = this.script;
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = false;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
  }

}
```

But I got this error:

> charset is deprecated. (deprecation)

[image: error]

How do I resolve this error in my Angular 7?

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the charset: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> If present, its value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for "utf-8". Both it’s unnecessary to specify the charset attribute, because documents must use UTF-8, and the script element inherits its character encoding from the document.

Comment: But when I added this:       <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js'"></i>
  I got an error:    Can't bind to 'appLoadscript' since it isn't a known property of 'i'

Comment: Is it in the declarations of your module?

Comment: @user11352561  The directive has to be listed in `declarations: [LoadscriptDirective]` in your `app.module.ts`.

Comment: It is declared in the app.module.ts.   I dont know why the problem is still there